# MS-Excel 2010... Cannot get VBA code in immediate window to work?

Tags: vba, excel

Basically I am debugging my code and I created a break point.  At this break point I want to check the address of a name range "Sales". I have looked up ways to do this and I have tried the following lines of code each and I always get a "run-time error 1004 Application defined or object defined error".  Here are the lines of code i have tried:

```
 ? Range(“Sales”).address
 Debug.Print Range(“Sales”).address
```

the following website claims these lines of code should work what am I doing wrong?http://excelexperts.com/Quick-Immediate-Window-Commands-useful-for-debugging

Comment: You already have a breakpoint. How about storing Range(“Sales”).address to a variable and watching its value in the Locals window? If it isn't shown, you can find it in the View-menu.

Comment: Probably means named range "Sales" doesn't exist.

Comment: It's possible that the reference for your named ranged has been broken e.g. the cell it referred to was deleted. Regardless of whether the named range doesn't exist or the reference is broken it's unlikely that the error you're receiving is the fault of the immediate window. I'm assuming you're attempting to debug this code because it wasn't working or was throwing an error, it might be worth asking a question about that instead to get to the bottom of the matter.

Comment: Do you actually have those curly quotes in the code? i.e. do you really have `“Sales”` rather than `"Sales"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can not comment yet. so:

Tried two lines of code in immediate window and got no error.
so, result is: named range "Sales" is missing in your workbook.

To find the named range enter this in immediate window:

```
Application.Goto Reference:="Sales"
```

if this "Sales" exist then range would be selected in your workbook.

Else Error '1004' will come: "the text you entered is not a valid reference or defined name."

OR,

You can find your named ranges in these areas:

Formulas tab --> Defined Names --> Name Manager

or 
Home tab --> Editing --> Find & Select --> Go To

Comment: Yes, your right I ended up having a name range of Sale not Sales